# How do you determine which dbclient connection property to use for an Oracle SQLWorkspace connection?

Tags: arcobjects, oracle-dbms, oracle-spatial

I have an Oracle11g database that I connect to via a SQL Workspace; however the actual dbclient string value that **works** differs depending on machine (and I'm guessing oracle client configuration).  On some machines, its `Oracle11g`(like the example on [resources.arcgis.com](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//001m00000039000000)):

```
// Create the connection properties.
IPropertySet connectionProps = new PropertySetClass();
connectionProps.SetProperty("dbclient", "Oracle11g");
connectionProps.SetProperty("serverinstance", "Riverside");
connectionProps.SetProperty("authentication_mode", "DBMS");
connectionProps.SetProperty("user", "BlackDog");
connectionProps.SetProperty("password", "123456");
```

Sometimes it's `Oracle`.

```
// Create the connection properties.
IPropertySet connectionProps = new PropertySetClass();
connectionProps.SetProperty("dbclient", "Oracle");
connectionProps.SetProperty("serverinstance", "Riverside");
connectionProps.SetProperty("authentication_mode", "DBMS");
connectionProps.SetProperty("user", "BlackDog");
connectionProps.SetProperty("password", "123456");
```

How is that dbclient value used by ArcGIS? Is there a way to detect which is needed at runtime?

Comment: What is in the tnsnames.ora C:\app\username\product\11.2.0\client_1\network\admin ? are both machines the same?

Comment: Sometimes there's nothing in the tnsnames.ora.  But we set the server instance connection directly: `(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=lorem)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=ipsum)))`. I prefer this option since the actual address name differs from machine to machine.

Comment: I'm still waiting to hear about all of the various configuration options.  But I can tell you that 1 machine has 2 11.2.0 32-bit clients installed.  `tnsping`s work fine, so I wasn't initially thinking it was tns related.

Comment: Which ArcGIS version are you running? The property set for connections to a sql workspace changed somewhere between 10.0 and 10.2.

Comment: 10.1 in this case. But I potentially have another AddIn  that runs in multiple versions where it would be nice to  be able to detect.

Comment: Are you using a SqlWorkspaceFactory or an SdeWorkspaceFactory?

Comment: SqlWorkspaceFactory.

Answer (score 1):

With 10.0 and Oracle 11g I can open an esriDataSourcesGDB.SqlWorkspaceFactory using a property set as you describe above. However from 10.1 forward I've had to change my programs to use esriDataSourcesGDB.SdeWorkspaceFactory and the following property set:

```
        IPropertySet propertySet = new PropertySetClass();
        propertySet.SetProperty("SERVER", "<servername>");
        propertySet.SetProperty("INSTANCE", "sde:oracle11g:<instancename>");
        propertySet.SetProperty("DATABASE", "");
        propertySet.SetProperty("USER", "<username>");
        propertySet.SetProperty("PASSWORD", "<password>");
        propertySet.SetProperty("VERSION", "sde.DEFAULT");
```

I wasn't able to find documentation that they've deprecated the SqlWorkspaceFactory but applications that I used it in worked in 10.0 and don't in 10.2. In Esri help is this remark in the SqlWorkspaceFactoryClass page:

> The SDEWorkspaceFactory.Open method should be used to make connections
>   to all databases and enterprise geodatabases.

Also there was a Knowledge Base tech article about it:
[What has changed in Query Layers between ArcGIS 10.0 and 10.1](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/41246)

I don't know how you would "detect" which properties your application needs other than try/catching in your code. You might see if using the SdeWorkspaceFactory works in all 10.x versions that you support and drop usage of SqlWorkspaceFactory if so.

Answer (score 1):

I had a devil of time trying to use a Direct Connection to Oracle.  At the end, I used a .sde file to load up in memory, then parsed out the PropertySet for it so I could see how it was working.

This code works for me:

> public static IWorkspace Connect(string serverName, int port, string dbName, string user, string password)
>           {
>
> ```
>         //"sde:oracle$//servername:1551/database1";
>         string instance = string.Format(@"sde:oracle$//{0}:{1}/{2}", serverName, port, dbName);
>
>         IPropertySet propertySet = new PropertySet();
>         propertySet.SetProperty("SERVER", "local_oracle");
>         propertySet.SetProperty("INSTANCE", instance);
>         propertySet.SetProperty("USER", user);
>         propertySet.SetProperty("PASSWORD", password);
>         propertySet.SetProperty("VERSION", "SDE.DEFAULT");
>         propertySet.SetProperty("AUTHENTICATION_MODE", "DBMS");
>
>
>         Type factoryType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("esriDataSourcesGDB.SdeWorkspaceFactory");
>         IWorkspaceFactory2 workspaceFactory = (IWorkspaceFactory2)Activator.CreateInstance(factoryType);
>         return workspaceFactory.Open(propertySet, 0);
>     }
> ```